# Do I need to use GoogleOauth for accessing calendar API

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have the public calendar in Google and I want to access the list of upcoming events.

I am reading their docs and I am getting confused with `OAuth`.

I have the public calendars I don't think I need any `OAuth`.

I am not able to find simple example in Python where I can access the events. Can anyone give me some code example of that? I am not able to find how to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an [XML or iCalendar feed](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en) of the calendar. Since it's a public calendar, there should also be a public feed listed. These do not require OAuth or any other form of authentication if the calendar is public.

Comment: But how can i query for upcoming events

Comment: you can use the parameters listed at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference?hl=de&csw=1#Parameters. You probably want futureevents=true

Comment: i tried that but i am not able to get events between two dates. i tried stat-min and start-max but i still get all events

Comment: you may try max-results=4 parameter.  The default value is 25.